# Can someone explain how Stanford university intermediate format (SUIF) works?

Tags: compiler-construction, intermediate-code

I recently encountered a term SUIF in a compiler design class. I tried to study about it but could not understand the overview of it from the documents of SUIF website. I could only get that it's based on object oriented style and follows a tree structure.
Can someone help me in understanding it? Even links other than SUIF websites would help me a lot.

Thanks.